# VS2010 x64: Array of objects containing wrong data in 64-bit platform VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit, porting

I am porting 32-bit code to 64-bit code in VS2010. My application is crashing when trying to lauch one of the dialog box but I found it works perfectly in 32-bit configuration but not in 64-bit. I found there is an array of objects which is containing array of characters, there data is not proper in 64-bit platform. eg. Suppose there is a list of strings: red, black,....In 32-bit, list is displayed correctly but in 64-bit 2nd object's character pointer points to k of Black i.e 4 bytes ahead of actual data. Object size is 144 bytes in 32-bit platform but in 64-bit it's 148 bytes for each object.

```
BOOL SomeDlg::OnInitDialog( HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam )
{
   MEMBERASSERT();
   CABCDialog::OnInitDialog( hwnd, hwndFocus, lParam );

   int nHeight = ListBox_GetItemHeight( GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_DUMMYLIST),    -1 );
   m_myLst.SetItemHeight(-1, nHeight);
   m_ClrLst.SetItemHeight(-1, nHeight);

   char smyItem[64];
   for (UINT i=0; i < 10; i++)
   {

      LoadString(g_hInstance, IDS_COLORNAMES+i, smyItem, ELEMENTS_IN(smyItem));
      m_ZAItems[i].SetColor(m_pSettings->m_rgbColors[i]);
      m_ZAItems[i].SetText(smyItem);

    //debug issue, check size of object
      int a = sizeof(m_ZAItems[i]);
      m_myLst.AddItem( &m_ZAItems[i] );
    }

//some other stuff
}

  class SomeDlg : public CABCDialog
   {
   private:
      MyDrwaLstBox m_myLst;
      My_ColorComboBox    m_ClrLst;
      My_ColorText  m_ZAItems[11];


   private:    
   SomeDlg();
   SomeDlg(const SomeDlg &);
   const SomeDlg &operator=(const SomeDlg &);


  public:   
     SomeDlg(HWND hwndZW, MCURRENT* pSettings , LPCSTR szName );
     virtual void Notification( ADM_Wnd *pWnd, UINT uID, int nNotificationCode, LPARAM lData );
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog( HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam );
  };

class MyDrwaLstBox : public MY_ListBox
{
protected:
   BOOL                          m_bpmn;
private:
                             MyDrwaLstBox( const  MyDrwaLstBox& );
   const MyDrwaLstBox &  operator=( const MyDrwaLstBox & );

public:
                             MyDrwaLstBox ();
   virtual void                  OnDrawItem( HWND hwnd,
                                         const DRAWITEMSTRUCT * lpDrawItem );
};


class My_ColorText : public My_Color
{
private:                                 
   enum { txtLen = 128 };    
   TCHAR m_szText[ txtLen ]; 

   My_ColorText ( const My_ColorText  & );
   const My_ColorText  &operator=( const My_ColorText  & );


public:
   My_ColorText ();
   My_ColorText ( COLORREF rgbColor, LPCTSTR pszText );

   void SetText( LPCTSTR pszText );
   void SetText( HINSTANCE hInstance, UINT uID );
   LPCTSTR GetText();

   virtual void Draw( HDC hDC, RECT rRect, BOOL bChecked, BOOL bDisabled,
                  BOOL bFocus, BOOL bGrayed, BOOL bSelected );
};

My_ColorText::My_ColorText()
{   
   m_szText[0] = '\0';
}

My_ColorText::My_ColorText( COLORREF rgbColor, LPCTSTR pszText )
 : My_Color( rgbColor )
{
   MDC_strncpyz( m_szText, pszText );
}

void My_ColorTex::SetText( LPCTSTR pszText )
{
  MDC_strncpyz( m_szText, pszText );
}

void My_ColorText::SetText( HINSTANCE hInstance, UINT uID )
{
  *m_szText = '\0';
  LoadString( hInstance, uID, m_szText, ELEMENTS_IN( m_szText ) );
}

LPCTSTR My_ColorText::GetText()
{
  return m_szText;
}

template <size_t size>
LPSTR MDC_strncpyz(CHAR (&dest)[size], LPCSTR srce) { return MDC_strncpyz(dest, srce, size); }


class My_Color : public My_DrawItem
{
private:
   COLORREF                   m_rgbColor;

private:
                          My_Color( const My_Color & );
  const My_Color &    operator=( const My_Color & );

public:
                          My_Color( void );
                          My_Color( COLORREF rgbColor );

  virtual void               Draw( HDC hDC, 
                                RECT rRect,
                                BOOL bChecked,
                                BOOL bDisabled,
                                BOOL bFocus,
                                BOOL bGrayed,
                                BOOL bSelected );
};

My_Color::My_Color void )
 : m_rgbColor( RGB_BLACK )
{
}

My_Color::My_Color( COLORREF rgbColor )
 : m_rgbColor( rgbColor )
{
}

 class My_DrawItem
{
protected:                             
   BOOL                       m_bInListBox;                              
   DWORD                      m_dwUser;
private:
                          My_DrawItem( const My_DrawItem & );
const My_DrawItem &  operator=( const My_DrawItem & );

public:
                          My_DrawItem();
virtual                    ~My_DrawItem();
virtual void               Draw( HDC hDC, 
                                RECT rRect,
                                BOOL bChecked,
                                BOOL bDisabled,
                                BOOL bFocus,
                                BOOL bGrayed,
                                BOOL bSelected );
};

My_DrawItem::My_DrawItem()
 : m_bInListBox( FALSE ),
m_dwUser( 0 )
{
}
```

'SomeDlg' class contains object of My_ColorComboBox class which in turn contains array of object of class My_ColorText.
 when contructor of My_ColorText class gets called through My_ColorComboBox class then difference of base addresses of m_ColorItems[0]'s m_szText and m_ColorItems[1]'s m_szText is equal to 152 bytes. Means My_ColorText() constructor assigns base address for m_szText variable at the differnce of 152 bytes. 
 But When contructor of My_ColorText class gest called through SomeDlg class then difference of base addresses of m_ZAItems[0]'s m_szText and m_ZAItems[1]'s m_szText is equal to 148 bytes. Hence strings are not getting inserted at proper location of difference of 152 bytes.

When I check sizeof(My_ColorText), in both cases it gives me 152 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, but your code provides very little information.  What is `MyDrwaLstBox`?  What are these "virtual functions" that you've left out?  Are you passing the `My_ColorText` by value to a function that takes `My_Color`, thus introducing object slicing?

Comment: please find full code

Comment: That is not "full code".  All of your classes have user defined copy constructors and assignment operators.  Those are some of the most important functions to get correct, but you didn't post the code for those.  One wrong move with those functions, and the whole program has undefined behavior.  And why does your class have these operators to begin with?  What's wrong with the default version of these functions?

Comment: copy constructors and assignment operators don't have any implementation in my code so I didn't provided.

Comment: I see that your copy constructor and assignment ops are private, so it seems ok.  However this: `m_ZAItems[i].SetText(smyItem)`  looks suspicious.  The parameter to this function must be an `LPCTSTR`, but you're passing a `char` pointer.  The two types are *not* the same, unless you're building an MBCS program.

Comment: I am building with Multi-byte character set

Comment: Few more findings has updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created objects on heap instead of creating on stack. 
Below lines have added to solve the problem.

```
for (UINT i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
   LoadString(g_hInstance, IDS_COLORNAMES+i, smyItem, ELEMENTS_IN(smyItem));
   //m_ZAItems[i].SetColor(m_pSettings->m_rgbColors[i]);
   //m_ZAItems[i].SetText(smyItem);

   myLst.AddItem( new  My_ColorText( m_pSettings->m_rgbColors[i], smyItem ) );
}
```